# truncate text on site javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way with javascript/jquery to search a site for text and if found changes it?

I have bedrooms and bathrooms across the site and i need it to change to bed baths.

Sorry this is such a generic question. I just need to know if you can do such a thing.

Comment: At least you gave some context. JavaScript is the wrong tool for the job (unless you're doing this serverside). How is your content managed?

Comment: Need more info to give you a specific answer, but if you're using MySQL to store that text, you can do a search/replace that way.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code?

Comment: Why don't you correct the source files directly? Using javascipt/jquery at frontend to modify static content would be a very bad way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done via Javascript. However, if you can I'd handle this on the server side. But, to answer your question, you can do this. Keep in mind that this can be extremely dangerous if not used carefully (I'm only providing a rough example). Where "foo" is the ID (or element) that contains what you're looking for and to replace. Also, this example uses jQuery but you can easily do this with pure Javascript.

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    <p>Bathroom</p>
    <p>Bedroom</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var elem = $("#foo").html(); // fetch the HTML from the #foo ID
var bath = "Bathroom"; // text to replace 
var bedroom = "Bedroom"; // text to replace
var replaceBath = "Bath"; // text to replace with
var replaceBed = "Bed"; // text to replace with
elem = elem.replace(bath, replaceBath); // replace & update string
elem = elem.replace(bedroom, replaceBed); // replace & update string
$("#foo").html(elem); // apply updated string to #foo
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EnJz5/1/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "change".  Remember that your browser downloads the page from the server.  If you change the page, you're only changing your copy, and even though you'll see the changes, it won't "stick" since the next time you view the page, it will once again download it from the server.

You may be able to do this with javascript using node.js, which unlike client-side javascript, will allow you to modify files on the server, however there are better ways of achieving this.  It really only amounts to finding text in some files and replacing them on the server, however if you're asking about how to change the page with javascript, I'm afraid you mean to say that you want to be able to change the webpage from the client side.

Such things are possible, but not without extensive support on the server, such as the case with mediawiki.  I hope that helps.